# Expresscheckout with Digital Goods not working in my account

Tags: .net, paypal

I have already created account which says that

> Your payment solution: PayPal Digital Goods (PayPal Express Checkout)

but i get an error that

> You are not signed in to accept payment for digital goods

Can anyone help to get me out of this error by setting up my existing account to accept digital payments?

My sandbox account id is **arjunpathak_tech@hotmail.com**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Paypal account setup issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for a sandbox account, I can enable it on the account if you can provide me with the email address of the actual sandbox seller account.  I did not see a dandbox account with the email address you provided.  Make sure this is the email address for the actual sandbox seller account, and not the email address for your developer account.

Comment: these are my sandbox accounts:- arjunpathak_tech@hotmail.com,

vcm_test_business@vcmpartners.com,

vcm_test_personal@vcmpartners.com.Kindly check these.

Comment: I show that you have digital goods enabled on your account with the email address of "vcm_test_business@vcmpartners.com"